# NodeJs : Using async for request url - Post method sending response before execution of all urls

Tags: node.js, async.js

I have a post method, whose request input is a list of newLink objects (newLink with attributes linkUrl and status)
I am using async.map for iterating over my URLs to check if the links are active or not.

newLinks contains links like {www.google.com,www.nourl.com,www.xyz.com} I am expecting like after all the request are processed and setting corresponding status as true or false, I want this to send using res.send(newLinks)

But the console is giving the below results: "www.google.com is up", then calling res.send(), then executing "www.nourl.com is up" and "www.xyz.com is up"

So basically here, after the first url request , my code below is executing the function outside the async loop. I thought async will only allow the next piece of code to execute only after all the urls are validated.

```
app.post('/myposturl', function(req , res){
var request = require('request');
let linkDetails= req.body.linkDetails;
var i = 0;
 async.map(linkDetails, function(newLink, callback) {
var Url = "url";
var url = newLink.linkUrl;
        var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': Url});
        proxiedRequest(url , function (error, response, body) {

          if(error){
            console.log('Err: '+ error);
          }
        if (!error) {
        if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || 
         response.statusCode == 202){
          console.log(url + ' is up!!');
          newLink.isActive = true;
        }

        if(response.statusCode == 301 || response.statusCode == 302){
          console.log(url + ' is redirecting us!!');
          return false;
        }
        }
        });
        callback();
        }  , function(err, linkDetails) {
       res.send(linkDetails);
        });
      //tried res.send here as well.
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try using async.mapSeries.

Comment: tried it, but no luck :(

Comment: Instead of async.map try async.series and use forin loop inside async.series. I tried it in one of my applications and it was working fine.

Comment: I tried those as well, but the problem is I am getting the response only after the res.send, basically it is not waiting till the response arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback` of `async.map`  should invoke inside `proxiedRequest`. What your code is doing now: invoke `callback` immediately before the `proxiedRequest` finished. Also `return false;` does not work in asynchronous function. You should return the new status like this `callback(null, newLink)`. After all the request are processed, the `newLinkDetails` will be the array of all `newLink`.

> Note, that since this function applies the iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

If you need to keep the order, user [mapSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries) insted.

Please read the [doc of async.map](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) for more. Hope it helps.

```
app.post('/myposturl', function(req , res){
  //other codes
  async.map(linkDetails, function(newLink, callback) {
    //other codes
    proxiedRequest(url , function (error, response, body) {
        if(error){
            console.log('Err: '+ error);
            callback(error);
            //^ ^  ^  ^  ^
            // Validation failed, return from here
        }
        else {
            //some validation & set newLink.isActive

            callback(null, newLink);
            // ^   ^    ^   ^    ^
            //return newLink status by invoking the callback
        }
    });
  }, function(err, newLinkDetails) {
      //err = if any Validation failed
      // now all the request are processed,newLinkDetails is array of all newLink's
      res.send(newLinkDetails);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when using `async.js`, I follow these two principles:

- Always call the `callback` at least AND at most once during your async function.
- Call the `callback` only when the async function is complete OR if an error has occurred. If the latter occurs, call the `callback` passing the `error` AND stop further execution of the async function e.g. `return callback(error)`

I would revise your code as below:

```
var request = require('request');

app.post('/myposturl', function (req , res) {
    async.mapSeries(req.body.linkDetails || [], function(newLink, callback) {
        var Url = "url";
        var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({ 'proxy': Url });
        proxiedRequest(newLink.linkUrl, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err)
                return callback(err);
            // I'm assuming you don't want to stop checking the links for bad status codes
            if ([301, 302].indexOf(response.statusCode) > -1){
                return callback(null, url + ' is redirecting us!!');
            if ([200, 201, 202].indexOf(response.statusCode) == -1) {
                return callback(null, url + ' came back with ' + response.statusCode);

            console.log(url + ' is up!!');
            newLink.isActive = true;    
            callback(null, newLink);
        });
    }, function (err, linkDetails) {
        // when all links get checked, it will come down here
        // or if an error occurs during the iteration, it will come down here
        console.log(err, linkdetails);
        res.send(linkDetails);
    });
});
```

If you only want to get back active links, you may also want to check out [async.filterSeries()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#filterSeries). Here the `callback` would need to be passed a boolean in its second argument.